# LiveCharts: How to convert chart to image using Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

I want to export [LiveChart](https://lvcharts.net/) chart to image using `WinForms`. What I found till now is only WPF related stuff.
https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/issues/243

Any help regarding `WindowsForms` will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can save your code using DrawtoBitmap method but to apply margin and padding 
add your livechart control to panel and save panel using DrawtoBitmap method.

```
var chart = panel1;

using (var bmp = new Bitmap(chart.Width, chart.Height))
{
    chart.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, chart.Width, chart.Height));
    bmp.Save("screenshotchart1.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u tried the [Chart.SaveImage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456181.aspx) method?

try the following code

```
this.chart1.SaveImage("C:\\mycode\\mychart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: I am working with LiveCharts (https://lvcharts.net) and believe that you are referring to Microsoft's Chart.

Comment: Try this and let me know if you have any issues [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As [Documentation says](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wf/start), have you tried the [RenderTargetBitMapClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx?)?